# Recommend a desktop app to monitor port 80 on servers

Tags: monitoring, ip

I did some googling but was unsuccessful, so I am posting here. I am looking to get an app (preferably free/open source) to monitor my servers on port 80 that would send me an email/text when some predefined timeout triggers. I could probably write something in VB to do this but i am burried with projects, why reinvent the wheel. I know there are services out there that want you to pay $5/month to do so, I was thinking about a Windows app that would sit on my computer and simply monitor predefined list of IPs on port 80.

Thanks!

Comment: nagios - its massively overkill for what you suggest - but costs nothing, is reliable, and very extendable.

Comment: symcbean - will it install on windows?

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/about.html#requirements says not.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/).  It's mainly a web app that will send you e-mail/text notifications for any downtime, and the timing is configurable.  It comes with a Windows app that will notify you if a site goes down.  It's free for a single site, and has a monthly fee for additional sites and other features.  I know it's not the same as just a desktop app, but it'll work better if you need reliable monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux box you can do a little script for monitor webservers.

A example of the script (put in the webserverlist.txt file all the servers that you want to monitor and set the params of timeout as you need):

```
#!/bin/sh

serverlist=`cat webserverlist.txt`

for i in $serverlist; do
echo $i
        wget --connect-timeout=2 --read-timeout=5 $i 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
                echo "ALARM: Webserver $i no OK" | mail -s "ALARM: Webserver $i no OK" my@email.com
        fi
done
```

Comment: thanks Mitch, anything for windows? :)

Comment: Install cygwin, then you can run this script in windows easily. Lifehacker.com has a decent intro: http://lifehacker.com/179514/geek-to-live--introduction-to-cygwin-part-i

Answer (score 1):

quick and free monitoring app

http://polymon.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks, i am checking out this app but its really confusing, the full version that requires database needs plugins in order to monitor TCP ports, but i cant find them anywhere on the site. the Real Time version does not monitor TCP ports.... :| am i missing something?

Comment: sorry I've been on vaca, but the non real time one will monitor a website out of the box no plugins necessary.  I have not used the real time one so I don'
t know anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

PRTG Network Monitor will do the trick for you. The free version allows up to 10 sensors, more then sufficient for a simple web server.

http://www.paessler.com/download/prtg

Remember to request the free license too.

The installation is a breeze. Simple and straightforward and awesome amount of features.